# getWidth() is not working inside looping over HashMap

Tags: java, events, canvas, hashmap, components

friends.
I'm trying to write the JAVA program that will draw graph based on the input that user will provide.  I have class that represents the canvas on which the graph of names is drawn. This class is responsible for updating (redrawing) the graphs whenever the list of entries changes or the window is resized. By taking data from file Im putting them into HashMap inside ItemGraph class and then looping over it in order to get necessary data to draw graphs.I faced an issue, that I can not reach getWidth() data inside HashMap loop, although same method gives me correct info in the code above(highlighted bold). Also when I'm trying to add() some GObjects, it does not work.Im really have no idea what is going on there and what is the problem.Will be grateful for all help.

public class ItemGraph extends GCanvas
implements ItemConstants, ComponentListener {

```
private HashMap<String, ItemEntry> entries;

/**
 * Creates a new ItemGraph object that displays the data.
 */
public ItemGraph() {
    addComponentListener(this);
    entries = new HashMap<>();
}

/* Method: addEntry(entry) */

/**
 * Adds a new ItemEntry to the list of entries on the display.
 * Note that this method does not actually draw the graph, but
 * simply stores the entry; the graph is drawn by calling update.
 */
public void addEntry(ItemEntry entry) {
    if (entry != null) {
        entries.put(entry.getName(), entry);
    }
    update();
}


/**
 * Updates the display image by deleting all the graphical objects
 * from the canvas and then reassembling the display according to
 * the list of entries. Your application must call update after
 * calling either clear or addEntry; update is also called whenever
 * the size of the canvas changes.
 */


public void update() {

    removeAll();

    double canvasHeight = getHeight();
    double canvasWidth = getWidth();

    double columnWidth = canvasWidth / NDECADES;

    for (int i = 0; i < NDECADES; i++) {
        double x = i * columnWidth;
 **System.out.println(columnWidth); all working here**
        GLine line = new GLine(x, 0, x, canvasHeight);

        GLabel decade = new GLabel(Integer.toString(START_DECADE + i * 10),
                x + GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE / 2, canvasHeight - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE / 3);
        add(line);
        add(decade);
    }

    GLine topHorizontalLine = new GLine(0, GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE, canvasWidth,      GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE);
    add(topHorizontalLine);

    GLine bottomHorizontalLine = new GLine(0, canvasHeight - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE,
            canvasWidth, canvasHeight - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE);
    add(bottomHorizontalLine);

    for (ItemEntry entry : entries.values()) {
        String gName = entry.getName();
**System.out.println(gName);all working here**
System.out.println(columnWidth);here i have 0**
        
        for (int i = 0; i < NDECADES; i++) {

            GOval oval = new GOval(10 * i, 10 * i, 10 * i, 10 * i);
            add(oval);

        }
    }
}


/* Implementation of the ComponentListener interface */
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
}

public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
}

public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    update();
}

public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
}
```

}

Comment: Does the ItemEntry class have a (public) getter for columnWidth?  If so, what is it called?

Comment: What is `GCanvas`? If it's anything like `java.awt.Canvas`, it should know its own width. Its width would be its parent container's width

Comment: Components only have a size once they have have been added to a visible frame and the frame has been packed or made visible.